# Click on a highchart series column

Tags: highcharts

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494683/highcharts-stacked-column-adding-onclick-event-to-the-chart) but it doesn't help me. How do I have an event fired when clickin anywhere in highlichted *combined* column?
Only clicks in one of the data columns is fired. Clicks on the light blue(cyan) area have no effect.

With these plot options:

```js
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation: { duration: 50 },
                events: {
                    click: function(e) {
                        console.log(
                            'x: ' + e.point.category + ', ' +
                            'y: ' + e.point.y + ', ' +
                            'series.name: ' + this.name
                        )
                    },
                }
            },
       }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `xAxis.crosshair` click event, but this option is not available in API. You can use the custom plugin to achieve that:

```
<script src="https://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/js/customEvents.js"></script>
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/57ygq23t/

Alternatively, depending on your use case, you can try to play around with the `chart.event` click, as in the following thread:

[Click event on highcharts chrosshair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749306/click-event-on-highcharts-chrosshair)

Comment: thanks. the fiddle is no longer tgere unfortunately .

Comment: What do you mean? Fiddle doesn't work?

Comment: Odd I got a not found error. It does now work.

Comment: The chart.event does not work in this case as clicks on the colored bars are ignored (z-order). I trye the blacklabel-thingy,

Comment: Unfortunately this.series is undefined there. I check with blacklabel

Comment: I'm not sure what would you like to achieve by clicking on the crosshair, could you clarify, please? The crosshair in the demo doesn't point out the series but the category anyway. I prepared the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zhsf0gt8/ where you are able to get the category. Let me know If that was helpful or If you need something else

Comment: I'm probably not sure what you mean by _crosshair_ . In the image I tried to explain that clicking on one of the colored year bars does get processed but I want to process on the complete area enclosing the year columns for one category. Just like the cyan  highlight is also around the colored year columns.

Comment: Thanks for you fiddle it does allmost that but shows something else if I click on the bright colored bars

Comment: The crosshair (highlighted, blue background) and columns should be considered as separate cases, and their click event functions should be adjusted accordingly. The columns can be considered as a series or as individual points. Both series and points have events that can be used. If you want to show the category after clicking the column, the easiest way is to use the point event:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jm3qa7w4/ ; API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the assistance and help I received here. It is a bit odd that such trivial event handling takes quite some fiddling but I include for future reference complete instruction on how to create the behavior I wanted.

### Store a handle to the chart:

```js
    const chart = Highcharts.chart('chart-container', {
```

We need the chart const at various moments in processing (`this` seems to refer to different things at different moments and cannot be used everywhere)

### Store the columnIndex

The `formatter` function is called when hovering over a series whenever the 'crosshair' is visible. The name 'crosshair' is not so obvious for a column chart but it is what I referred to as the light blue background change when hovering eiter of a series or a category. This it the only place where the `columnIndex` is visible to javascript and this will stored in a variable in the chart object. This can be achieved with this code unf `tooltip` `formatter` function:

```js
        tooltip: {
            shared:true,

            formatter: function() {
                chart.columnIndex = chart.xAxis[0].categories.indexOf(this.x);
            }
        }
```

added somewhere in the options and assumed you create the chart variable. The `shared: true` makes sure it combines the series in a category.

Two types of clicks are distinguished by Highcharts. Clicks on series (the bright colored bars in my example) and clicks in the category *outside* the series (the area that lights up lightblue (cyan) when hovering over the chart area. The later is only available from the Blacklabel custom events add on.

### Click on the series

A click on one of the bright colored bars is handled in the series section under `plotOptions`:

```js
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                    click() {
                        console.log('series click on ', chart.columnIndex)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here we use the columnIndex that was stored in the formatter function and added to the `chart` object

### Click on the category

Is not processed normally and here we need the `customevents.js` library as @magdalena pointed out (thank you, magdalena). Include this in your html:

```html
<script src="https://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/js/customEvents.js"></script>
```

*after* including the highcharts library.
Now events can be added to the `xAxis` `crosshair` section:

```js
        xAxis: {
            crosshair: {
                enabled: true,
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        console.log('category-click on ', chart.columnIndex)
                    }
                }
            }           
        },
```

In the console you can see the clicks on either the category or the series along with the index of the category.

### Common handling

To add a common function for both events add this function after you created the chart:

```js
    chart.columnClick = function() {
        console.log('click on ', this.columnIndex);
    }
```

and add `chart.columnClick()` to the two click event functions.

## User feedback

In order to signal the user one can actually click the category pointed to is equally complex due to the z-index of the various elements. Adding a pointer cursor to the Series is not that hard. Under `plotOptions`, `series` add a cursor line

```js
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',

            }
        }
```

But to add the same cursor to the category this could be handled in your css:

```
#chart-container
    .highcharts-crosshair-category
        cursor: pointer
```

A `'zoom-in'` can of course be used as well.